# Angular.js ng-repeat inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to repeat an array of objects and an array of images. I would like each one image to be repeated with each object. My problem is if I nest the ng-repeat inside another ng-repeat, it repeats all the images every time. My code is below. I hope this makes sense. Thanks.

```
            <div class="feed-content">
            <div ng-repeat="feed in feeds | filter:filterText" class="article animate-repeat">
                <h3>{{feed.title}}</h3>
                {{feed.content | limitTo:100}}<br/><span class="read-more"><a href="#">Read More</a></span>
            </div>
            <div ng-repeat="img in imgs" class="article-image" style="background-image: url('{{img}}');"></div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your second loop is outside the parent loop, also you might want to use `imgs` field from each `feed` object in the parent loop, so you're probably need something like `ng-repeat="img in feed.imgs"`

All in all you're looking for something like this structure

```
<div ng-repeat="feed in feeds">
  <h3>{{feed.title}}</h3>...
  <div ng-repeat="img in feed.imgs">...</div>            
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I should have been a little more clear. The problem is if I nest the ng-repeat="img in imgs" in the parent loop if will repeat all the images every time the parent loop repeats. I want to repeat one image per feed repeat.